# Does independent two sample t-test suffice for comparing the percent of female in two groups?

Tags: t-test, experiment-design, proportion

I have two groups of an experiment, and I want to show first that they are similar in terms of demographics. One of the demographic factors is gender. I've looked for the most recommended way to compare the proportion of females in the two groups - I found some mixed answers about proportions comparison and wondered - why can't I just treat the IsFemale variable as a numeric (0/1), and than run independent 2 sample t-test on the groups (which will provide the differences between the %female)? Are there any risks in this method?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=t-test+proportion

Answer (score 0):

The two-sample t-test will allow you to assess whether there is a significant difference in the means of the two groups.

However, if you are using a t-test, you are assuming the distributions of both groups are close to normal. With your binary variable, this assumption will not hold.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a recomendation for this type of comparison?

Comment: Because your data doesn't have a distribution (and an associated variance), finding a valid statistical test is problematic...